# Difference between Page refresh and Page postback

Tags: asp.net

My question is - what is the difference between page refresh (if I press f5) and postback (If I press a button)?

Can anyone please tell me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A refresh mean a complete reload of the page, without any form data. This is essentially an HTTP `GET`.

A post back is when the page is posted to itself (through the `form action=""`). This is essentially an HTTP `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Oded.
Can you also please tell me is also there any difference between when I press f5 and when I select the URL and press Enter key? :)

Comment: @Mohit Kumar - When pressing F5, you may end up re-posting form data (the broswer normally warns about it). When selecting the URL and entering, this will be a _new_ request.

Comment: Thanks again Oded.
I dint understand what is meaning of "you may end up re-posting form data". Could you please explain?

Comment: @Mohit Kumar - It means that if the page you are seeing is a result of a repost, pressing F5 may cause another repost.

Answer (score 4):

Lets have the actual difference between refresh and explicitily submitting a page :

1) Refresh does not mean to post back the page with get method..(You can check it with response.write request.form("some input type")).

2)Difference lies with the data sent to the server :
in case of explicit submit form is submitted with latest value(i.e it recognize the changes in form elements)
But in case of refresh, form is submitted with default form value.(i.e if you change the value of form element it will not reflect at server.)

Answer (score 0):

when page is refresh that means page is sending request to server without any `data` that means `HTTP GET` but in another case suppose a event is fired that causes postback after 
page completely load on browser if we press `f5 or do refresh` then it will send privious data with `request instance`, that means again for that data server will perform operation...
have u seen somtimes while you are doing online sopping after selecting item and press accepet button uyou get total price ,now again if you refresh then for that selected item it will again go to server that means you are buying same things twice.....i think now you get everything what i want to say...

```
                           in  when page is postback then code of that page again compile and also processing `request data`. this process will going on
```